# WebApi POST method not found but GET works

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, webapp2

I tried many time today to call a web api function with POST (***HttpClient.PostAsync***) method . But unfortunately I can't. 
Only the call with GET (***HttpClient.GetAsync***) method working with success. 
I try to follow many sample on the net, but always the same error. ("Not Found")

Thank you so much if somebody can help me

**Here is the C# Web API:**

```
[RoutePrefix("NewAreaMap")]
public class NewAreaMapController: ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("PostCreateAreaTemp")]
    public AreaTemp PostCreateAreaTemp(double southLatitude, double westLongitude, double northLatitude, double eastLongitude, int countryId, int worldId)
    {
        AreaTemp newTempMap = new AreaTemp();
        //.....
        * * Here is the C# code from client side: * *
            using(var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SrvWebApiPath"].ToString());
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var values = new Dictionary < string,
                    string > ()
                    {
                        {
                            "southLatitude", southLatitude.ToString()
                        },
                        {
                            "westLongitude", westLongitude.ToString()
                        },
                        {
                            "northLatitude", northLatitude.ToString()
                        },
                        {
                            "eastLongitude", eastLongitude.ToString()
                        },
                        {
                            "countryId", countryId.ToString()
                        },
                        {
                            "worldId", worldId.ToString()
                        }
                    };
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/NewAreaMap/PostCreateAreaTemp", content)
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    newAreTemp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < AreaTemp > (jsonData);
                }
        }
```

The GET call work well with the following Url :

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/NewAreaMap/GetAreaTemp/?latitudeAreaCenter=7.02&longitudeAreaCenter=9.05");
```

Comment: Does the webserver log show anything more interesting other than 404?

Comment: What URI are you trying to POST to? Please also include the GET URI.

Comment: I add in the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're posting a JSON, you might as well send it as an object. Or if you still want to keep the dictionary and the signature for the method you could try:

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values),
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Instead of

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
```

Here's an example with an object.

```
public class SampleObject
{
    public double SouthLatitude { get;  set; }
    public double WestLongitude { get; set; }
    public double NorthLatitude { get; set; }
    public double EastLongitude { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int WorldId { get; set; }
}
```

And change your request.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SrvWebApiPath"].ToString());
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var obj = new SampleObject
    {
        SouthLatitude = southLatitude,
        WestLongitude = westLongitude,
        NorthLatitude = northLatitude,
        EastLongitude = eastLongitude,
        CountryId = countryId,
        WorldId = worldId
    };

    // Send it as StringContent.
    var request = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj),
        Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/NewAreaMap/PostCreateAreaTemp", request)
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string jsonData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        newAreTemp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AreaTemp>(jsonData);
    }
}
```

And the signature on the server.

```
public AreaTemp PostCreateAreaTemp(SampleObject sampleObject)
```

Or if needed:

```
public AreaTemp PostCreateAreaTemp([FromBody]SampleObject sampleObject)
```

Comment: Thank you, everthing goes well now. Many thanks, you take many times for me and write a full pretty answer as a sample code.

Comment: Out of curiosity; did you need to use `[FromBody]`? I never learn when it's needed or not...

Comment: @smoksnes true, same thing here because it works without using it. i saw man time developer like me use it or sometime not , seems it just attribute provide from microsoft for safer side.

Comment: No i don't need :-) . Its work well without [FromBody]

Answer (score 2):

> replace your method parameter with object because you are passing full object 
>   "content" from the httpclient so in that case you need to use same object here also with [frombody] attribute 
>   methodname([FromBody] Content content)
>   define all the properties in one class and use . Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks , i give you one point , like @smoksnes  said. Is a part of the answer

Comment: @MehdiBugnard thanks , i posted before but i respect smoksnes answer he posted answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use **FromBody** attribute with your action parameter.

Comment: Can we use frombody attribute with no of parameters ?